# facing some issues while integrating google maps in my angular 8 project

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular7, angular-google-maps, angular8

Implementing gooogle maps for my angular project,
I have used `@google/maps` with angular 8.
And I am getting this error:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/@google/maps/lib/internal/make-url-request.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in '/var/www/html/googleMap/node_modules/@google/maps/lib/internal'

I have gone through all stack overflow solutions but nothing helped me

my `package.json` file:

```
    {
      "name": "google-map",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
        "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
        "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
        "@google/maps": "^0.5.5",
        "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
        "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.1",
        "tslib": "^1.9.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
        "@types/googlemaps": "^3.37.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.1.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.15.0",
        "typescript": "~3.4.3"
      },
      "browser": {
        "crypto": false
      }
    }
```

I need to overcome this problem please help 
or if anyone of you are integrated google maps in your projects please provide github link, it will be really helpful.

Comment: are you trying to use the google-maps library made for JS in Angular? you would have to try something like this: https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/

Comment: fixed that issue
just i've created new file called index.d.ts and added - declare module 'googlemaps';
and  imported using -import {} from 'googlemaps';